# Func<T> with dynamic quantity of parameter types

Tags: c#, generics

I need to write a method wich consumes other methods as "actions" to do something with it (for example logging).

Here is my method:

```
public static void Call(Func<T, TResult> action){
  Log.Debug(action.Method.Name + " method called");
}
```

and now I want to stick in every possible method, like

```
private void Method1 (string param1, int param2) { ...}
private ServiceResult Method2 (UserInfo param1, string param2, bool param3, double param4) { ... }
```

and I want to call it like

```
Call(Method1); // output: "Method1 method called"
Call(Method2); // output: "Method2 method called"
```

My problem is, that I need to declare fix parameter types for the "Func<>" parameter for my Call-Method. How could I do that in a dynamic/generic way?

EDIT: I work on .NET Compact Framework, so I have only .NET 3.5 CF available and can't use every Class or Type.

Comment: If you don't know the method name at compile time, look into `[CallerMemberName]`. If you do, use `nameof`.

Comment: Aside from anything else, this doesn't sound great from a code readability perspective... you really don't want to have to add something to *every method* manually (and have to read that code). You might want to look into AOP frameworks for .NET.

Answer (score 3):

When you only want to access the metadata of the delegates, use the `Delegate` class:

```
public static void Call(Delegate action){
  Log.Debug(action.Method.Name + " method called");
}
```

If you want to *call* the delegates, things get more complicated:

There are 9 versions of the`Acton` and 9 versions of `Func`: each from zero to eight parameters. If you want direct support for all variants of these delegates, you need 18 overloads of your `Call` method.

That seems excessive and it actually is, especially since you also need to add one parameter in your methods for each parameter in the delegates. I would recommend to go with two overloads and use lambda expressions:

```
public static void Call<T>(Func<T> action)
{
    return action();
}

public static void Call(Action action)
{
    action();
}

private void ExampleWithParams(int param1)
{
    //...
}

private int ExampleWithParamsAndReturn(int param1)
{
    //...
    return param1;
}
```

Call them like this:

```
Call(() => ExampleWithParams(0));

int value = Call(() => ExampleWithParamsAndReturn(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since all you need from your `Func<T,TResult>` is `Method`, from which you harvest its name, you can use [`Delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class, from which all delegates, including `Func<...>`, inherit:

```
public static void Call(Delegate action){
    Log.Debug(action.Method.Name + " method called");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using lambda expressions, then those will allow you to inspect both the method being called and its parameters. The parameters can even be method calls themselves, as I will show.

Here is a working example that you can stick in a Console app to test:

```
private static void TestLogAnyMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n>> First batch >>");
    var x = M1(0, 1.1);
    var y = M2("a", true);
    var z = M2(GetA(4, 5.0 / 7.0), GetTrue());

    Console.WriteLine("\r\n>> Second batch >>");
    var x2 = Log(() => M1(0, 1.1));
    var y2 = Log(() => M2("a", true));
    var z2 = Log(() => M2(GetA(4, 5.0 / 7.0), GetTrue()));

    Console.WriteLine("\r\n>> Results >>");
    Console.WriteLine(x + " == " + x2);
    Console.WriteLine(y + " == " + y2);
    Console.WriteLine(z + " == " + z2);
}

private static string GetA(int p, double q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("-- Executing GetA");
    return "a";
}

private static bool GetTrue()
{
    Console.WriteLine("-- Executing GetTrue");
    return true;
}

private static string M1(int v1, double v2)
{
    return "123abc";
}

private static bool M2(string w1, bool w2)
{
    return true;
}

private static T Log<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    var funcBody = (MethodCallExpression)expr.Body;
    var funcArgs = funcBody.Arguments;
    Console.WriteLine("Method call: " + funcBody.Method.Name + "(" + string.Join(", ", funcArgs.Select(p => p.ToString())) + ")");

    Func<T> f = expr.Compile();
    return f();
}
```

I used non-trivial test cases to convince myself that GetA() and GetTrue() are called only once inside Log(...), and more specifically only when `f();` executes.

Output:

```
>> First batch >>
-- Executing GetA
-- Executing GetTrue

>> Second batch >>
Method call: M1(0, 1.1)
Method call: M2("a", True)
Method call: M2(GetA(4, 0.714285714285714), GetTrue())
-- Executing GetA
-- Executing GetTrue

>> Results >>
123abc == 123abc
True == True
True == True
```

Comment: It works like a charm! unfortunately I work on .NET Compact Framework and "Expression" is not available there. I Should add this info in my question. But perfect answer as well